# Django App not Deploying Correctly on Azure Web App Service

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been following the steps outlined in the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=django%2Cwindows%2Cvscode-aztools%2Clocal-git-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli#3---deploy-your-application-code-to-azure) to deploy my Django app on an Azure Web App Service using local git deployment. After completing the steps, I can see the code and the virtual environment with the correct packages when I SSH into the web app.

However, when I visit my site, it still loads the default Azure home page instead of my Django app. I attempted to troubleshoot by running `python manage.py runserver` in the SSH console, but I received the following error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 12, 2024 - 01:20:11
Django version 4.1, using settings 'csvvalidator.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

It seems like the Django development server is running, but the port is already in use. I expected my Django app to be deployed following the tutorial, but it's not working as expected.

Am I missing any additional steps or configurations to ensure that my Django app is properly deployed on the Azure Web App Service? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your DJango application code?

Comment: The application has many files and folders. What specific file or configuration do you want to see?

Comment: Are you able to successfully deploy the Django web application that you have created?

Comment: Can you share the git repository if there is not sensitive information in it?

Comment: I can't share it because contains a lot of sensitive info

Answer (score 0):

The Error mentioned in the above indicates there is already running another application in the same port check all terminals as tried as earlier.

To run in another port, can you try `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080` command.

Restart the application once and check.

I have created sample Django application by taking the GitHub [reference](https://github.com/smahesh29/Django-WebApp/tree/master)

The Django application executed successfully  by using `python manage.py runserver` command. check below:

[image]

[image]

I have created one repository in GitHub and by using below commands successfully pushed the Django application into Repository.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit message here"
git remote add origin <repository_url>
git push -u origin master
```

[image]

I have created azure web app service with deployment option GitHub. make sure enable the basic authentication in deployment settings.
[image]

Set below App settings in environment variables. like below:
[image]

The above Django application successfully deployed into the azure web app.  for the deployment status check below:

[image]

**In portal:**

[image]
[image]

Firstly i also got same error which you mentioned in the above, then i checked all the terminals and closed in the local which is running in the same port. then it works like below:

[image]

when I accessed the azure app service URL getting like below:

[image]

Comment: I tried the command `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080` ant the app starts but when I go to the url site nothing happens. Simply the app doesn't load.

Comment: Verify that your Django settings are correctly configured, especially the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in your settings.py file. If 127.0.0.1 or localhost is not included in ALLOWED_HOSTS.